# How to set layout weight in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have 4 views & I need to divide them in group of 2 & then make them cover spread in the area.

I have try using `Group` & `chainStyle` but nothing  could satisfy 100%.

I want,
[image]

I have managed to make this,
[image]

Code for the same is given below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorBtnPink"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivFb"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:background="@color/colorBgBtnFbDark"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_facebook"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvFacebook"
    style="@style/tvSmallPopMedium"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:background="@color/colorBgBtnFacebook"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_regular"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_regular"
    android:text="@string/action_facebook"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/ivFb"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivTwitter"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:background="@color/colorBgBtnTwDark"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tvFacebook"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_twitter"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTwitter"
    style="@style/tvSmallPopMedium"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:background="@color/colorBgBtnTwitter"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_regular"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_regular"
    android:text="@string/action_twitter"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/ivTwitter"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You can use LinearLayout for use weight in layout

Comment: @ShivamKumar, I know that solution but want to implement using `ConstraintLayout` only.

Comment: I think ConstraintLayout does't have property of weight

Comment: set layout_width to 0dp. It means the size of the view is determined by the constraints.

Comment: `ConstraintLayout` does provide property `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent` but I am unable to manage it with 4 views & `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle`.

Comment: @Tura What views should I set `0dp`, all 4 views?

Comment: @buzzingsilently did you tried using guidelines ? If not take a look at my answer and try.

Comment: @buzzingsilently If you set the widths of all the views with 0dp, then the layout is totally controlled by constraints. So they would have equal widths. Anyway, check Mehran's answer. It looks like greate approach in your case.

Comment: you can use two `LinearLayout`, one for each button with `android:layout_width="0dp"`  and `android:layout_weight="1"`

Comment: @Umair Yes It worked with minor changes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also use `guideLines` property something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorBtnPink"
android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivFb"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:background="@color/colorBgBtnFbDark"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_facebook"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvFacebook"
    style="@style/tvSmallPopMedium"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:background="@color/colorBgBtnFacebook"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_regular"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_regular"
    android:text="@string/action_facebook"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/ivFb"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/ivTwitter"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivTwitter"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorBgBtnTwDark"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tvFacebook"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_twitter"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTwitter"
    style="@style/tvSmallPopMedium"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:background="@color/colorBgBtnTwitter"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_regular"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_regular"
    android:text="@string/action_twitter"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/ivTwitter"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

See if this completes your requirement.

Comment: @buzzingsilently Yes I gave you the idea. and glad it worked, Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 2):

You should modify your code as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/ivFb"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
   android:clickable="false"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvFacebook"
   app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
   app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
   app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"
   tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/tvFacebook"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
   android:clickable="false"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:text="Facebook"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivFb"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivTwitter"
   app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
   app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivFb"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/ivTwitter"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
   android:clickable="false"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvTwitter"
   app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
   app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvFacebook"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
   app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"
   tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

 <TextView
   android:id="@+id/tvTwitter"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
   android:clickable="false"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:text="Twitter"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivTwitter"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
   app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivTwitter"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It will look like[image: this]

I modified your code for arranging elements in constraint layout, Now you can modify the code as per your need :)

Comment: You don't need to include `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"` in each chained view, you should only add it to the first view in chain

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_savewd"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="#3b5998"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/asdfsff"
    tools:ignore="RtlCompat">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_save"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Facebook"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_save"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_save"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="facebook"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button_save"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/asdfsff"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:background="#444"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button_savewd"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlCompat">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_twitter"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_0"
        android:text="Facebook"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_twitter"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_twitter"
        android:text="Twitter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/img_twitter"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
     </RelativeLayout>
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> setting the width of each item to 0dp or MATCH_CONSTRAINT lets the views fill the parent (optional)

Output :

[image]

Comment: just why do you think they introduced `ConstraintLayout` to the sdk?! it's exacctly so people don't do what you did here, nesting relative layouts unnecessarily like this. besides, why would you include `layout_constraintxxxx` attributes inside `RelativeLayout` children?! stop giving bad advice, people

Answer (score 0):

Apply Following Steps:

1. Select your widget and set chains to Horizontal
2. Select your widget and set it to Horizontally Center
3. Select your widget and set it to Organise (Expand Horizontally).

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, to use chainStyle, you must to given start & end constraints(if chainStyle=horizontal) whereas top and bottom constraints for chainStyle=vertical